# UFW Deny not really working

Tags: networking, webserver

I tried to block an IP address from my server using the command:

```
sudo ufw deny from 15.15.15.51
```

I restarted the server and checked the rule with:

```
sudo ufw status -v
```

Which returned:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
2323/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        15.15.15.51
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2323/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

After checking, the IP still have access to my server, it is not dropping the connections. What could be happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question after finding the answer: I found the problem was with ordering. Deny rules should go first, I had to show the rules numbered with:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

Then deleting the rule with:

```
sudo ufw delete 4
```

Then adding it first with:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 15.15.15.51
```

Then reloading with

```
sudo ufw reload
```

Now it's working.

Comment: Version 0.36.0 has the "prepend" command that can be used instead of "insert 1": `ufw prepend deny from 15.15.15.15/8`